# Windows 8 Store App: Using multiple RichTextColumns in a flipview control

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to show two columns of rich text in two languages (side by side) inside a flip view. How Do I create two columns inside RichTextColumns and bind them to two different data source?

The flip view control looks like this:

`FlipView
            x:Name="flipView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">

```
        <FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,137,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <!--
                    UserControl chosen as the templated item because it supports visual state management
                    Loaded/unloaded events explicitly subscribe to view state updates from the page
                -->
                <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid>

                        <!-- Content is allowed to flow across as many columns as needed -->
                        <common:RichTextColumns x:Name="richTextColumns" Margin="117,0,117,47">
                            <RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" Width="560" Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="ምዕራፍ "/>
                                    <Run FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding ChapterNumber }"/>
                                    <LineBreak/>

                                    <!--<Run FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding Subtitle}"/>-->
                                </Paragraph>

                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="{Binding ChapterContent}"/>
                                </Paragraph>

                            </RichTextBlock>

                            <!-- Additional columns are created from this template -->
                            <common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <RichTextBlockOverflow Width="560" Margin="80,0,0,0">
                                        <RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="4"/>
                                        </RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                                    </RichTextBlockOverflow>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
                        </common:RichTextColumns>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state inside the FlipView -->
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                                <!-- Respect the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextColumns" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="97,0,87,57"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="400"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <!-- When snapped, the content is reformatted and scrolls vertically -->
                                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextColumns" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="17,0,17,57"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="scrollViewer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="280"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="160"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>`
```

Answer (score 2):

If the columns are going to be displaying two separate pieces of information, can you not jus make two separate richtextcolumns, have them inside grids, which are then inside the flipview. That way you can bind the each RichTextColumn to the source that you want.